# Is POJO Servlet ever considered?

Tags: spring, servlets, jakarta-ee, pojo

POJO is the norm in Spring but also pervasive in the Java EE world. One non-POJO stronghold is Servlet. I'm wondering if any open source ever appeals to change.

POJO examples:

> class MyHttpServlet { @Inject void
>   doGet (@HttpServletRequest Request
>   request, @HttpServletResponse Response
>   response) {..} }
>
> class MyOtherServlet { @Inject void
>   doOther (@OtherServletRequest Request
>   request, @OtherServletResponse
>   Response response) {..} }
>
> class MyOneWayServlet { @Inject void
>   doOneWay (@OneWayServletRequest Request
>   request) {..} }
>
> .....

Maybe it's all about how to make POJO/SoC/loose-coupling pragmatically.

Spring's taking on EJB2.x is straight replacing it that later yields to EJB3.x, but on Servlet adding a MVC layer above (like other web frameworks doing theirs).

Orginally i was asking if someone envisioned the radical way on Servlet. The answers seem to me clearly none.

Comment: I didn't understand anything.

Comment: Can you explain what you're asking a little better?

Comment: When the Servlet 3 spec was being designed, there was indeed a discussion of having the Servlet annotations applicable to POJOs (no base class, no interface), but this was rejected by the community.

Answer (score 3):

I understand that you're asking for POJO-flavored alternatives to [`Servlet`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/Servlet.html), is this correct?

There are none. It's the core building stone of a Java EE webapplication. It provides a mandatory application programming interface to intercept on HTTP requests. There are however a lot of Java EE based MVC frameworks which abstracts the whole `Servlet` away so that you end up with basically a Javabean (or POJO as *you* call it) as model and a JSP/(X)HTML page as view. Examples of such are JSF, Spring MVC, Struts2, Wicket, etc.

There's no need to reinvent `Servlet`. It's a mature and solid building stone. Just abstract it away using a MVC framework if it disturbs you.

Comment: i add examples that might make web/servlet container more vibrant thanks to POJO.

Comment: I think you confused the meaning of term POJO. Your code example shows DI and that's less or more already what Spring MVC is doing.

Comment: The examples appeal that web/servlet container needn't tighten to http request/response objects but may inject various types of them, by compositing the "POJO" servlet with the desingated tranport "SERVICE" (http/other/oneway...) .

Comment: Still, this require the "raw" Servlet API to do its work in the background. Right now you're basically asking for Servlet API-provided annotations to inject the request/response objects. Well, basically there's only the `@WebServlet`. For the remnant this just look like more an idea for *another* MVC framework which abstracts the Servlet API away using the kind of annotations as shown in your example.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the Spring-MVC Controllers:
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-controller

If I understand correctly, this is what you are looking for